# Raspberry Pi FileZilla SSH Permissions

Tags: ssh

Thanks for your help previously. I have now set my Pi up as a web server and when I go to remotely connect via SSH in FileZilla (OS X), I get the following errors when attempting to add/remove a file in certain directories:

```
Response:   200 Type set to A
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,2,4,190,243).
Command:    STOR index.php
Response:   550 index.php: Permission denied
Error:  Critical file transfer error
Status: Disconnected from server
```

Help please! :)

I'm trying to get in to the /var/www/ directory and add files here. Tried various types, and this is where I should upload my web server files.

I'm running Wheezy OS on my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I think the directory permissions do not allow you to write files in this directory. You have two options: 1. Open up this directory for writing (and the parent directories), this is NOT the best idea, 2. Configure FileZilla to use a different directory to store it's files, for example a separate (new) directory in the /home tree might be a good choice.

Comment: How would I do that? I only got my Raspberry Pi on Christmas Day so I'm not an expert... Preferably opening up the directory for writing?

Comment: The commands to change file / directory permissions is 'chmod', [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/) you find a little info about this command, more in depth information can be found [here](http://catcode.com/teachmod/)

Comment: Could you check out the post below please, @Ikku? :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your SSH user doesn't have write permission to /var/www, I'm guessing you are using pi@raspberrypi to connect SFTP. If you want to write there, you can simply run (assuming you have a user named www-data to represent your web server):

- sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www *(This one gives /var/www to www-data user/group)*
- sudo chmod -R 664 /var/www/ *(This one lets group users read/write, everyone else only read)*
- sudo usermod -aG www-data pi *(Adds your user to www-data group)*

Comment: With 664 I got a 'Forbidden' error. I tried 777 and now I get this when trying to connect... Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 192.168.x.x:21...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: Not being a FileZilla expert :), I just searched for the error message online and found the following links that might be useful: [FileZilla Forum](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=7876) and one on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687900/connection-attempt-failed-with-econnrefused-connection-refused-by-server) that eventually links to the network config documentation. All the info in there suggests it might have something to do with the network config of filezilla or a router or some firewall.